# How to get retrieving five lines of input at a time and echoing them five times each on clojure

Tags: loops, input, clojure

My code is

```
    (loop[
       su[5]
       (let mo[(read-line)])
       ]
   (println mo))
```

I wrote like this.
But,I have many error.

My image is...

input 1 string
→
input 1 string
→
input 1 string
→
input 1 string
→
input 1 string
→
output 1 string
→
output 1 string
→
output 1 string
→
output 1 string
→
output 1 string

Comment: This is not even close to something that could resemble working Clojure code.  I'd recommend reading a good introductory book or website, e. g. “Clojure for the Brave and True”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just read in 5 lines and print out the result:

```
(let [mo (for [_ (range 5)]
           (read-line))]
  (println mo))
```

Comment: This has an unintended side effect of `for` being lazy.
That is while it works for `(range 5)` it breaks for `(range 33)` or everything above that size. Clojure lazy seqs are usually chunked where first 32 elements evaluated at once.
Better to wrap with `doall` or use `mapv`.

Comment: @Juraj Martinka tried with up to 50 elements and it still worked.  Tried using Clojure v1.8.0 using CodingGround online Clojure IDE by replacing 5 with various numbers up to 50, with sufficient input on stdin.

Comment: I don't say it doesn't work at all but it works differently: that is they aren't read _all_  first and only then printed but they are read up to 32 lines and then printed and then rest is read and printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something `n` times, especially when side-effects such as printing are invovled, `dotimes` is there for you:

```
(dotimes [_ 5] (println (read-line)))
```